# Как отключить подсветку одинакового синтаксиса в PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Вот нажимаю на "print" и все "print", которые есть в коде тоже выделяются.
Как это убрать подскажите пожалуйста?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы уже искали в настройках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings → Editor → General → Highlight on Caret Movement → Highlight usages of element at caret
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое))